# how to write ByteArrayOutput in .wav file

Tags: java, android, arrays, audio

I am trying to write the audio data into ByteArray and when the button is clicked I am trying to write the data into .wav file But file is not even getting created even though i have data into bytearray here is what i have used the following code I am able to make file directly when to the .wav file

```
public class Wavrecordernew {
private static final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV = ".wav";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "Automator";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE = "record_temp.raw";
private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100;
private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

private static AudioRecord recorder = null;
private static int bufferSize = 0;
//bufferSize *= 2;

private static Thread recordingThread = null;
private static boolean isRecording = false;
private static String filenme, wavpath;
private static ByteArrayOutputStream mainBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

// bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);


static String getFilename() {
    String filepath = wavpath;
    File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + filenme);
}


static String getTempFilename() {
    String filepath = wavpath;
    File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    File tempFile = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);

    if (tempFile.exists())
        tempFile.delete();

    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);
}

// audio recorded file name and path passed from main activity
public static void startRecording(String filepathfrmdis, String filenamefrmdis) {

    bufferSize = (AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT));
    filenme = filenamefrmdis;
    wavpath = filepathfrmdis;
    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

    int i = recorder.getState();
    if (i == 1)
        recorder.startRecording();

    isRecording = true;

    recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            writeAudioDataToFile();
            adddatatorecorder();

        }
    }, "AudioRecorder Thread");

    recordingThread.start();
    new java.util.Timer().schedule(
            new java.util.TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    stopRecording();
                }
            },
            9000
    );

}


private static void writeAudioDataToFile() {
    byte data[] = new byte[bufferSize];
    Log.e("addbuffer", "" + bufferSize);
    String filename = getTempFilename();
    FileOutputStream os = null;

    try {
        os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int read = 0;

    if (null != os) {
        while (isRecording) {
            read = recorder.read(data, 0, bufferSize);

            if (AudioRecord.ERROR_INVALID_OPERATION != read) {

                try {
                    os.write(data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public static void adddatatorecorder() {
    int i;
    byte[] bArr = new byte[bufferSize];
    do {
        try {
            i = recorder.read(bArr, 0, bufferSize);
            try {
                mainBuffer.write(bArr, 0, i);
                Log.e("addbuffer", "" + mainBuffer.size());
            } catch (Exception unused) {
            }
        } catch (Exception unused2) {
            i = 0;
        }


    } while (i >= bufferSize);

}

public static void stopRecording() {
    if (null != recorder) {
        isRecording = false;

        int i = recorder.getState();
        if (i == 1)
            recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();

        recorder = null;
        recordingThread = null;
    }

    copyWaveFile(getTempFilename(), getFilename());
    deleteTempFile();
}

// if there is an existing file with same path and file name it will delete that temp file
static void deleteTempFile() {
    File file = new File(getTempFilename());

    file.delete();
}

private static void copyWaveFile(String inFilename, String outFilename) {
    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    long totalAudioLen = 0;
    long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
    long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
    int channels = 2;
    long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels / 8;

    byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];

    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
        totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
        totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;

        //AppLog.logString("File size: " + totalDataLen);

        WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);

        while (in.read(data) != -1) {
            out.write(data);
        }

        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// writing data from bytearray to .wav file
public static void copyWaveFilefrombytearr(String inFilename, String outFilename) {
    FileInputStream in = null;
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    long totalAudioLen = 0;
    long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
    long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
    int channels = 2;
    long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels / 8;


    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(inFilename);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
        totalAudioLen = in.getChannel().size();
        totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;

        //AppLog.logString("File size: " + totalDataLen);

        WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);


        mainBuffer.writeTo(out);


        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//Wav file header required to set the 44byte for wav file
private static void WriteWaveFileHeader(
        FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
        long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels,
        long byteRate) throws IOException {

    byte[] header = new byte[44];

    header[0] = 'R'; // RIFF/WAVE header
    header[1] = 'I';
    header[2] = 'F';
    header[3] = 'F';
    header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
    header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[8] = 'W';
    header[9] = 'A';
    header[10] = 'V';
    header[11] = 'E';
    header[12] = 'f'; // 'fmt ' chunk
    header[13] = 'm';
    header[14] = 't';
    header[15] = ' ';
    header[16] = 16; // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
    header[17] = 0;
    header[18] = 0;
    header[19] = 0;
    header[20] = 1; // format = 1
    header[21] = 0;
    header[22] = (byte) channels;
    header[23] = 0;
    header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
    header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
    header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
    header[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8); // block align
    header[33] = 0;
    header[34] = RECORDER_BPP; // bits per sample
    header[35] = 0;
    header[36] = 'd';
    header[37] = 'a';
    header[38] = 't';
    header[39] = 'a';
    header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
    header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
    header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
    header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

    out.write(header, 0, 44);
}
```

}

Comment: `copyWaveFilefrombytearr` Wrong function name. You copy an existing file. Better: `copyWaveFile`.

Comment: `mainBuffer.writeTo(out);` ? What is `mainBuffer`?

Comment: `in.read(data)` Check how many bytes are read. `int nread=in.read(data)...`

Comment: Mainbuffer is the ByteArrayOutputStream object

Comment: I replaced in.read(data) with mainBuffer.writeTo(out); @blackapps

Comment: copywavfile is the file that i used to write it from byte and that is working but when i try it with byteArray it is not working

Comment: Please show complete actual code.

Comment: I have updated the question and added the complete class

Comment: `file.mkdirs()` If you call mkdirs then check the return value. If it returns false then stop. `if (!file.mkdirs()) return null;`